# Change avatar on themed profile page

Tags: themes, login, dashboard, profiles, avatar

I'm using the Theme My Login plugin and trying to allow subscribers to change their profiles to one uploaded from their computer.

I've tried the following plugins:

- Simple Local Avatars
- User Avatar
- WP User Avatar
- Avatar manager

I can get the file upload form to appear, but when clicking upload or update profile, the avatar does not change.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Here is the whole of my 'Theme my login' profile code with 'Simple Local Avatars'

```
<div class="login profile" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
             <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'profile' ); ?>
             <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
             <form id="your-profile" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'profile' ); ?>" method="post" class="validate"<?php do_action( 'user_new_form_tag' );?>>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_' . $current_user->ID ); ?>
                <p>
                   <input type="hidden" name="from" value="profile" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="checkuser_id" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" />
                </p>

                <?php if ( has_action( 'personal_options' ) ) : ?>

                <h3><?php _e( 'Personal Options' ); ?></h3>

                <table class="form-table">
                <?php do_action( 'personal_options', $profileuser ); ?>
                </table>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php do_action( 'profile_personal_options', $profileuser ); ?>

                <h3 class="nomargin"><?php _e( 'Name' ); ?></h3>

                <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                   <th><label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_login ); ?>" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text" /> <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Your username cannot be changed.', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <th><label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->first_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <th><label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->last_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <th><label for="nickname"><?php _e( 'Nickname' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->nickname ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <th><label for="display_name"><?php _e( 'Display name publicly as' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td>
                      <select name="display_name" id="display_name">
                      <?php
                         $public_display = array();
                         $public_display['display_nickname']  = $profileuser->nickname;
                         $public_display['display_username']  = $profileuser->user_login;

                         if ( ! empty( $profileuser->first_name ) )
                            $public_display['display_firstname'] = $profileuser->first_name;

                         if ( ! empty( $profileuser->last_name ) )
                            $public_display['display_lastname'] = $profileuser->last_name;

                         if ( ! empty( $profileuser->first_name ) && ! empty( $profileuser->last_name ) ) {
                            $public_display['display_firstlast'] = $profileuser->first_name . ' ' . $profileuser->last_name;
                            $public_display['display_lastfirst'] = $profileuser->last_name . ' ' . $profileuser->first_name;
                         }

                         if ( ! in_array( $profileuser->display_name, $public_display ) )// Only add this if it isn't duplicated elsewhere
                            $public_display = array( 'display_displayname' => $profileuser->display_name ) + $public_display;

                         $public_display = array_map( 'trim', $public_display );
                         $public_display = array_unique( $public_display );

                         foreach ( $public_display as $id => $item ) {
                      ?>
                         <option <?php selected( $profileuser->display_name, $item ); ?>><?php echo $item; ?></option>
                      <?php
                         }
                      ?>
                      </select>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                <h3 class="nomargin addmargintop20"><?php _e( 'Contact Info' ); ?></h3>

                <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                   <th><label for="email"><?php _e( 'E-mail' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_email ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <th><label for="url"><?php _e( 'Website' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_url ); ?>" class="regular-text code" /></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                   foreach ( _wp_get_user_contactmethods() as $name => $desc ) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                   <th><label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'user_'.$name.'_label', $desc ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->$name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                   }
                ?>
                </table>

                <h3 class="nomargin addmargintop20"><?php _e( 'About Yourself' ); ?></h3>

                <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                   <th><label for="description"><?php _e( 'Biographical Info' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5" cols="30"><?php echo esc_html( $profileuser->description ); ?></textarea><br />
                   <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Share a little biographical information to fill out your profile. This may be shown publicly.' ); ?></span></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                $show_password_fields = apply_filters( 'show_password_fields', true, $profileuser );
                if ( $show_password_fields ) :
                ?>
                <tr id="password">
                   <th><label for="pass1"><?php _e( 'New Password' ); ?></label></th>
                   <td><input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" size="16" value="" autocomplete="off" /> <span class="description"><?php _e( 'If you would like to change the password type a new one. Otherwise leave this blank.' ); ?></span><br />
                      <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" size="16" value="" autocomplete="off" /> <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Type your new password again.' ); ?></span><br />
                      <div id="pass-strength-result"><?php _e( 'Strength indicator', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></div>
                      <p class="description indicator-hint"><?php _e( 'Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).' ); ?></p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </table>

               <?php
                 global $current_user;
                 get_currentuserinfo();
                 $myAv = new simple_local_avatars();
                 $myAv->edit_user_profile($current_user);
               ?>


                <p class="submit">
                   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
                   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                   <input type="submit" class="button-primary kopa-button blue-button small-button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update Profile' ); ?>" name="submit" />
                </p>


             </form>

          </div>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't link to the gravatar upload page?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I'm not sure what the gravatar upload page is?  But I want the avatar change to happen on the profile page, without going anywhere else. I want to keep things simple and also mobile device compatible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it working using the WP User Avatar plugin.

I added this to Theme My Login's profile-form.php, copied to the root of my theme folder.

```
<?php
   global $current_user;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   do_action('edit_user_avatar', $current_user);
?>
```

Then I added this to my functions.php file:

```
function my_avatar_filter() {
  // Remove from show_user_profile hook
  remove_action('show_user_profile', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile'));
  remove_action('show_user_profile', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts'));

  // Remove from edit_user_profile hook
  remove_action('edit_user_profile', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile'));
  remove_action('edit_user_profile', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts'));

  // Add to edit_user_avatar hook
  add_action('edit_user_avatar', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile'));
  add_action('edit_user_avatar', array('wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts'));
}

// Loads only outside of administration panel
if(!is_admin()) {
  add_action('init','my_avatar_filter');}
```

Everything seems to work as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

I also use Simple Local Avatars with Theme my login .
I have had the same problem.
My solution is very simple .Check form in profile-form.php template directory.
And add enctype attribute to form (enctype="multipart/form-data" )